# How to make the MediaController visible throughout my video play

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I am using MediaController in my app. But unfortunately the MediaController disappears after a time period of 3 secs. But I want my MediaController to be visible until my video plays fully.

How to achieve this.

Comment: Can you show some parts of code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the MediaController hides itself after 3 secs of time. In order to make it visible throughout our video playback we will have to override the hide() of MediaController. I have given the code snippet below.

```
final MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this) {
    @Override
    public void hide()
    {
       mc.show();
    }

    }); 

video.setMediaController(mc);
```

Comment: You can use `mc.show(0)` to set no timeout, which will reduce how often hide() is called. It will still be called if you tap on the view.

Comment: @DavidCaunt Setting this `int timeout` parameter made no difference to the `MediaController` hiding. Andro's method work, however.

Answer (score 2):

For stop hiding the MediaController we can make a new Mediacontroller by extending the base class. Then we can disable the hide method by simply overriding it. For getting the actual hide functionality, we can fetch the hide() method in base class. We can hide the Mediacontroller after playback is completed using that.
Here is the code for MediaController:

```
public class MediaController_2 extends MediaController{
public MediaController_2(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public void hide() {
}
public void hidecontroller()    {
    super.hide();
}
}
```

Now the mediacontroller won't be hiding even after the completion of the playback. For hiding the controllers after completing playback we can use OnCompletionListener.

```
        MediaController_2 mediaController = new MediaController_2(getActivity());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();   
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaController.show(0);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaController.hidecontroller();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

### More Succinct

First off, using an `int timeout` as a parameter in the `show()` method did nothing for me.

Secondly, this succinct piece of code forced the controls to stay on the screen after the first touch:

```
// Assumes you have a VideoView in your layout called 'video_preview'.
VideoView videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_preview);

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this) {                                                        
    @Override
    public void hide() {}      // Prevent hiding of controls.
};

videoPreview.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VideoView videoPlayer;
MediaController mediaController;

videoPlayer = view.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);
videoPlayer.setVideoURI(uri);
mediaController = new MediaController(getContext()) {
    @Override
    public void hide() {}      // on hide do nothing
};
videoPlayer.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoPlayer.requestFocus();
videoPlayer.start();
```